# ROCR cutoff value and accuracy plots

Tags: r, statistics, analysis, roc

I have a continuous independent variable (let's say 'height') and a binary independent variable (let's say 'gets a job'). I want to see at what cutoff value for height best predicts one's ability to get a job. I also want to see how accurate this model is. I assumed a multinomial logistic model. I wanted a ROC curve so I used the ROCR package in R. This was my code:

```
mymodel <- multinom(job~height, data = dataset)
pred <- predict(mymodel,dataset,type = 'prob')
roc_pred <- prediction(pred,dataset$job)
roc <- performance(roc_pred,"tpr","fpr")
plot(roc,colorize=T)
```

Now, this is my question. When I colorize the plot, it gives me the range of cut-off values used to make the plot. I'm a little confused as to what the cutoff values actually are though. Are the cutoff values the heights? Or the probability that a certain data point (person) with a certain height is able to get a job? I have a feeling it's the latter, but I am interested in the former. If it is the latter, how do I obtain the cutoff value for the height??

Answer (score 1):

I found a video that explains the cutoffs you see: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YdNhNfJ4Vl8

There are many different ways to estimate optimal cutoffs: Youden Index, Sensitivity + Specificity,Distance to Corner and many others (see [this article](https://ncss-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/themes/ncss/pdf/Procedures/NCSS/One_ROC_Curve_and_Cutoff_Analysis.pdf))
I suggest you use a `pROC` library to do so

```
library(pROC)
roc <- roc(fit, obs, percent = TRUE)
roc.out <- coords(roc, "best", ret = c("threshold", "sens", "spec"), transpose = TRUE)
```

method "best" uses the Younden index (J- index) The maximum value of the Youden index is 1 (perfect test) and the minimum is 0 when the test has no diagnostic value. The minimum occurs when sensitivity=1−specificity, i.e., represented by the equal line (the diagonal) in the ROC diagram. The vertical distance between the equal line and the ROC curve is the J-index for that particular cutoff. The J-index is represented by the ROC-curve itself.